# How to push array using if else condition

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've array

```
var getData = [
  {
    "value": "20,
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "value": "30",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "value": "40",
    "id": 6
  },
]
```

And I've data for example I want to check if `product_id =2` 
 I want to push `['product_id': 'thisistest']` into getData `id = 2`
the output will look like this

```
var getData = [
  {
    "value": "20,
    "id": 2,
    "product_id": "thisistest"
  },
  {
    "value": "30",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "value": "40",
    "id": 6
  },
]
```

Here is what I've try

```
for(let i in getData){
  const data = getData[i];
  //product_id ==2 
  if(data.id == product_id) {
    getData.push({
      //how can I push data into getData where id = 2
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You have broken object literal not closing quote in first id `"value": "20,` it should be `"value": "20",`, your code will never run, you should have error in console.

Comment: `data['product_id'] = 'thisistest';` (inside your if condition) is just enough instead of that `getData.push`, since those items are **objects**, not **arrays**. Of course, as long as `product_id` is 2.

Comment: thanks to all advice and comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` as well:

```js
var getData = [
    {
        "value": "20",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "value": "30",
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "value": "40",
        "id": 6
    },
]

var product_id = 4
var res = getData.map(x => x.id === product_id 
    ? ({...x, product_id: "thisistest"}) : x)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hi ,It's working Thank you. I know some people asking this kind of question but I'm new but still don't know about keyword to search it. I'm very appreciate to your answer. I'll mark green

Comment: @TryHard No need for apologizing, that's why SO is here :-) You can accept the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `map()`

Please Note: You are missing closing `"` in `"value": "20` which makes the object invalid.

```js
var getData = [
    {
        "value": "20",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "value": "30",
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "value": "40",
        "id": 6
    }
]

getData = getData.map(item => {
  if(item.id == 2)
    item["product_id"] = "thisistest";
  return item;
});

console.log(getData);
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is working too but I feel very sorry I've to mark the first answer .I'm very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
const change = (srchID, newKey, newValue) =>
getData.map(res => {
    if (res['id'] === srchID) {
        res[newKey] = newValue
    }
    return res
})
```